# I am facing error while installing R package textshaping

Tags: r, installation, devtools

I am getting this error while installing packages.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’

- removing ‘/home/Saniya/R/si-s/renv/staging/1/textshaping’
  Error: install of package 'textshaping' failed [error code 1]

What is wrong and what should I do. I am new with R. Please help.

Comment: Please include the command that you used for installation and the **complete** error, warning or other messages. Also the operating system and whether you are installing from source or not.

Comment: You might try installing a binary with `utils::install.packages("textshaping", type = "binary")`.

Answer (score 20):

1. In bash:

   ```
   sudo apt install libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev
   ```
2. in RStudio

   ```
   install.packages("textshaping", dependencies = TRUE)
   ```

Comment: on RHEL 8: `sudo yum install harfbuzz-devel fribidi-devel`

Comment: for those using macos : brew install harfbuzz fribidi

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to follow this package directly in R, and later found that using conda or mamba is so simple:

```bash
conda install -n R4.32 -c conda-forge r-textshaping
```